# How do I turn non-sequential data in R into sequential data while grouping on an ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(Person = c("Eric","Eric","Eric","Joe","Joe","Joe"), Order = c(2,7,4,2,5,1),
                 Value = c("A","A","B","C","A","B"))
```

The order column is currently in a random order. Every person has 3 order values which are random integers between 1 and 8. Order is always a value between 1 and 8, and there are no repeats for a person. How do I transform the Order column so that it is reflecting the order of the values, grouped by the person? Thus,  the order column would always between 1 and 3. The desired output would look like this.

````
df <- data.frame(Person = c("Eric","Eric","Eric","Joe","Joe","Joe"), Order = c(1,3,2,2,3,1),
                 Value = c("A","A",'B","C","A","B"))```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, we need to `rank` the 'Order' grouped by 'Person'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Person) %>%
   mutate(Order = rank(Order))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some base R options

- Using `rank`

```
  df,
  Order = ave(Order, Person, FUN = rank)
)
```

- Using `match` + `sort`

```
transform(
  df,
  Order = ave(Order, Person, FUN = function(x) match(x,sort(x)))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Order := frank(Order), Person]
df

#   Person Order Value
#1:   Eric     1     A
#2:   Eric     3     A
#3:   Eric     2     B
#4:    Joe     2     C
#5:    Joe     3     A
#6:    Joe     1     B
```